# Jenkins Maven Build Step fails but runs from command line

Tags: maven, jenkins

I've been searching the web and StackOverflow for a solution. Problem is that Jenkins will not invoke `mvn` from the the build step. In my build step, I'm using *Invoke top-level Maven targets*. From the command line `mvn clean install` runs just fine from the directory where the POM file is located. So I believe Maven is installed correctly.

From the console I see:

```
[XXXX] $ cmd.exe /C "mvn -f C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\pom.xml clean install && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
```

Error message is:

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What I have tried:

1. change the settings file option to point too the `settings.xml` in the Maven install folder
2. change the global setting file option to point too the `settings.xml` in the Maven install folder
3. I've set the `MAVEN_HOME` environment variable in Jenkins Configure System

What I expect to happen:

1. Maven to build my project from the build step.

Comment: Did you configure a Maven version in the tools section ?

Comment: Yes, there is a Maven Configuration section and the two dropdowns are set to use the "Use Default Maven Settings"  The Maven installations section is not setup.  thank you for the support

Comment: try to use the other Maven version , and send me the log PLS do see if it download it

Comment: Has to be a path problem. When I create a "Execute Windows Batch Command" and try "mvn clean install" this does not work? but if I run the cmd.exe and navigate to the top directory with where the pom is and execute "mvn clean install" that works fine.  Jenkins thinks MAVEN_HOME is C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9 and the PATH variable is set to C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin

Comment: Here is the console output from the job. The job is setup to run a simple batch command.C:\Users\XXX\workspace\XXXXX>exit 0 
[XXXX] $ cmd /c call C:\windows\TEMP\jenkins5516646072209472116.bat

C:\Users\XX\workspace\XXXXX>mvn clean install 
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\XXXX\workspace\XXXXX>exit 9009 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: when you change MVN version , did the job install a new Maven version ?

Comment: I did not change my MVN version. I believe it works just fine. It does not work when Jenkins wants to call it.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed pom.xml file from the path.. it's worked ..

So try the below option

[image]